# How to split a dataset to N equally-sized groups and assign them a number

Tags: r

I have `50 000` rows of data. And I want to make samples (splits?) from this data. `Sample-1` may contain `2` groups, each of size `25 000`. `Sample-2` may contain `5` groups, each of size `10 000`, etc. And I want to have a column in which there will be a value, depending on the number of groups. In case of `Sample-1`, for example, in this column I will see a random sequence of `1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2`. In case of `Sample-2`, I will have `1,3,2,1,4,1,5,...`. I do not know how to approach this problem in `R` and I hope there is a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Have you tried `?sample`?

Comment: I've seen it here - http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/02/how-to-choose-a-random-number-in-r.html. It seems like it can help to build a vector of random numbers. But I do not know whether it guarantees the equal number of groups.

Comment: @akrun For example, I've just done it like so `x2 <- sample(1:2, 6, replace=T)` and I got `2 2 2 1 2 1`. So there are four occurrences of 2 and only 2 occurrences of 1

Comment: You should also consider that you cannot perfectly divide all groups. i.e. split 10 rows into 3 equally-sized groups.

Comment: @ Pierre Lafortune. I know that and I do not consider all groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
f <- function(n.row, n.group) {
    sample(rep(seq_len(n.group), length.out = n.row))
}

## A few sample runs
f(3,2)
# [1] 1 2 1
f(5,2)
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2
f(10,4)
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 4 3 2 4 3 1
```

You'll notice that, when the number of groups does not cleanly divide the number of rows, the "extra" items are put into the groups in counting order. If it's important to you that this not happen (i.e. that group 1 not always get the first extra item), you could modify the function above like so:

```
f2 <- function(n.row, n.group) {
    ii <- sample(rep(seq_len(n.group), length.out = n.row))
    sample(seq_len(n.group))[ii]
}

## Check that overall frequency of group assignment isn't skewed
f2(3,2)
# [1] 2 1 1
f2(3,2)
# [1] 2 1 2
f2(3,2)
# [1] 2 1 2
```

Comment: For perfect devisors will it guarantee equally-sized groups? In case of `f(50,2)` will you get 25 of `2`s and 25 of `1`s?

Comment: "when the number of groups does not cleanly divide". And when it cleanly divides, will the size of groups be equal? I'm asking this, because I only consider perfect divisors: f(50,2), f(50,5), f(50,10) etc,

Comment: Yes, it guarantees that. (To see why, have a look at what you get by doing `rep(seq_len(n.group), length.out = n.row)`, which in the case you mention is essentially doing `rep(1:2, length.out=50)`.)

Comment: If you are only considering perfect divisors, then you can without reservations go with my function `f()` instead of my `f2()`.

Comment: Hm. Please have a look at this code: `sample(rep(1:5, length.out=10))`. As a result I got `4 4 3 5 5 3 2 1 1 2`. Is not it a counter-example?

Comment: Whereas I supposed to get something like `1 3 2 5 4 2 3 4 5 1`

Comment: The example for your `Sample-2` in the OP certainly doesn't seem to satisfy the additional requirement implied by your comment just above...

Comment: Sorry, it's ok. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 2):

Provide a vector with unordered groups to `sample`.

```
n.group <- 2
n.row <- 10
unordered <- rep(
  seq_len(n.group),
  each = n.row / n.group
)
sample(unordered)
```

`seq_len(n.group)` creates a vector with group numbers from 1 to the number of groups.
`rep` repeats each group number as defined in each
`sample` shuffles the order of the group numbers

In case `n.row/n.group` is not guaranteed to integer you can use this

```
n.group <- 3
n.row <- 10
unordered <- rep(
  seq_len(n.group),
  each = ceiling(n.row / n.group)
)
sample(unordered, size = n.row)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It works. But can you, please, drop a couple of lines to explain how it works?

Comment: And by the way, will you solution generalize over arbitrary number of groups?

Comment: @Josh O'Brien. Yes, I also noticed that. Probably, I was too fast to accept the answer