# Multiple random samples without replacement in R

Tags: r, sample, multisampling

I have a vector of size `M = 2630`, How can I draw `4` samples of size `M/4`. 
The following code is not working

```
M <- c(1:2630)
mysample <- split(sample(M), 1:(length(M)/4))
```

Since `(length(M)/4)` is not an integer, So I would like to make three samples of equal size and the fourth will have the rest of the units. Three samples can be of size `657` and the fourth one can be `659`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: FYI `length(M)` is 1. Do you mean `length(seq(M))`? (or just M)...?

Comment: I have edited the question and included M

Comment: Possible duplicate since the problem just seems to be creating equal groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262795/how-to-split-a-dataset-to-n-equally-sized-groups-and-assign-them-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way using a separate index vector `idx`:

```
n <- length(M)
set.seed(1)
idx <- sample(rep(1:4, each = ceiling(n /4))[1:n])

M1 <- M[idx == 1]
M2 <- M[idx == 2]
M3 <- M[idx == 3]
M1 <- M[idx == 4]
```

Or you use the `split` function:

```
split(M, idx)
```

Note that I set a random seed using `set.seed` to make the results reproducible.

You can use `table` to check the values of `idx`:

```
table(idx)
idx
  1   2   3   4 
658 658 658 656
```